# Installation just crashes with Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: gnome, system-installation, ubiquity

I'm trying to install Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 on my XPS 13, and every time after entering the user details (username, password, computer name, ...), the installer just closes. No error message, nothing.

Starting Ubiquity from a terminal at least yields a `Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`, but I have no clue where it's putting the core file (I tried disabling apport (and of course already sent a report) but that didn't change anything)...

This happens with UEFI *and* legacy boot, with third party software installation activated *and* without, with internet connection *and* without and with an external DVD drive (using a DVD I successfully used to install Ubuntu on my desktop computer) *and* a freshly downloaded image from an USB stick.
RAM is still good too, according to Memtest86.
It also doesn't matter how long I wait in the user details screen (while it's already copying files in the backgroung) - it happens while copying files and installing the base system, always just a few seconds after I click "continue". There also isn't an image above the process as usually, maybe that has something to do with that...?!

`dmesg` is here if that helps anything, there were a few errors on startup: https://qbin.io/a3fcglux

Anybody has any clue what could be causing that or how to fix it?!
Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, and as weird as it is that it doesn't work out of the box, it's even weirder that it actually *did* work out of the box on my desktop computer:

Start a terminal, and run `sudo ubiquity`. The important part here is the "sudo" - although Ubiquity generally seems to work just fine without it (partitioning and everything up to actually displaying the progress bar (which seems to be the actual issue according to the syslog) all works), it seems like somewhere it causes a problem.